# Find how many sundays in a month asp classic

Tags: date, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to use asp classic to find how many working days (mon - sat) are in the month and how many are left.

any help or pointers greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can find the number of Sundays in a month without iteration. Somebody posted a JavaScript solution a few months back and I ported it to VBScript:

```
Function GetSundaysInMonth(intMonth, intYear)
    dtmStart = DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, 1)
    intDays = Day(DateAdd("m", 1, dtmStart) - 1)
    GetSundaysInMonth = Int((intDays + (Weekday(dtmStart) + 5) Mod 7) / 7)
End Function
```

So, your total work days would just be the number of days in the month minus the number of Sundays.

**Edit:**

As @Lankymart pointed out in the comments, the above function gives you the number of Sundays in the month but it doesn't tell you how many are left.

Here's another version that does just that. Pass in any date and it will tell you how many Sundays are left in the month starting with that date. If you want to know how many Sundays are in a *full* month, just pass in the first day of the month (e.g., `DateSerial(2014, 8, 1)`).

```
Function GetSundaysRemainingInMonth(dtmStart)
    intDays = Day(DateSerial(Year(dtmStart), Month(dtmStart) + 1, 1) - 1)
    intDays = intDays - Day(dtmStart) + 1
    GetSundaysRemainingInMonth = Int((intDays + (Weekday(dtmStart) + 5) Mod 7) / 7)
End Function
```

**Edit 2:**

@Cheran Shunmugavel was interested in some specifics about how this works. First, I just want to restate that I didn't develop this method originally. I just ported it to VBScript and tailored it to the OP's requirement (Sundays).

Imagine a February during a leap year. We have 29 days during the month. We know from the start that we have four full weeks, so each weekday will be represented at least four times. But that still leaves one addition day that's unaccounted for (`29 Mod 7 = 1`). How do we know if we get an extra Sunday from that one day? Well, in this case, it's pretty simple. Only if our start date is a Sunday can we count an extra Sunday for the month.

What if the month has 30 days? Then we have two extra days to account for. In that case, the start date can be a Saturday or a Sunday and we can count an extra Sunday for the month. And so it goes. So we can see that if we're X additional days within an upcoming Sunday, we can count an extra Sunday.

Let's put this in tabular form:

```
            Addl Days Needed
Day         To Count Sunday
----------  ----------------
Sunday      1
Saturday    2
Friday      3
Thursday    4
Wednesday   5
Tuesday     6
Monday      7
```

So what we need is a formula that we can apply to these situations so that they all result in the same value. We'll need to assign some value to each day and combine that value with the number of addition days needed for Sunday to count. Seems reasonable that if we assign an *inverse* value to the weekdays and add that to the number of additional days, we can get the same result.

```
            Addl Days Needed  Value Assigned
Day         To Count Sunday   To Weekday      Sum
----------  ----------------  --------------  ---
Sunday      1                 6               7 
Saturday    2                 5               7
Friday      3                 4               7
Thursday    4                 3               7
Wednesday   5                 2               7
Tuesday     6                 1               7
Monday      7                 0               7
```

So, if `weekday_value + addl_days = 7` then we count an extra Sunday. (We'll divide this by 7 later to give us *1* additional Sunday). But how do we assign the values we want to the weekdays? Well, VBScript's `Weekday()` function already does this but, unfortunately, it doesn't use the values we need by default (it uses 1 for Sunday through 7 for Saturday). We could change the way `Weekday()` works by using the second param, or we could just use a `Mod()`. This is where the `+ 5 Mod 7` comes in. If we take the `Weekday()` value and add 5, then mod that by 7, we get the values we need.

```
Day         Weekday()  +5  Mod 7
----------  ---------  --  -----
Sunday      1          6   6
Saturday    7          12  5
Friday      6          11  4
Thursday    5          10  3
Wednesday   4          9   2
Tuesday     3          8   1
Monday      2          7   0
```

That's how the `+ 5 Mod 7` was determined. And, with that solved, the rest is easy(er)!

Comment: Good old `Mod()` again, but that doesn't give you the number of weekdays (whatever the OP defines as weekdays) past and future, I bet with a bit of manipulation you could get that.

Comment: Do you mind adding some explanation of how this method works? Why add 5 to `Weekday(dtmStart)` and not some other number?

Comment: I've added some info on the `+ 5` for you, @CheranShunmugavel.

Answer (score 0):

[@Zam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3111800/zam) is [on the right track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25381918/692942) you need to use `WeekDay()` function, here is a basic idea of how to script it;

```vb
<%
Dim month_start, month_end, currentdate, dayofmonth
Dim num_weekdays, num_past, num_future
Dim msg

'This can be configured how you like even use Date().
month_start = CDate("01/08/2014")
month_end = DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("m", 1, month_start))

msgbox(Day(month_end))

For dayofmonth = 1 To Day(month_end)
  currentdate = CDate(DateAdd("d", dayofmonth, month_start))
  'Only ignore Sundays
  If WeekDay(currentdate) <> vbSunday Then
    num_weekdays = num_weekdays + 1
    If currentdate <= Date() Then
      num_past = num_past + 1
    Else
      num_future = num_future + 1
    End If
  End If
Next

msg = ""
msg = msg & "Start: " & month_start & "<br />"
msg = msg & "End: " & month_end & "<br />"
msg = msg & "Number of Weekdays: " & num_weekdays & "<br />"
msg = msg & "Weekdays Past: " & num_past & "<br />"
msg = msg & "Weekdays Future: " & num_future & "<br />"

Response.Write msg
%>
```

Comment: This was a quick attempt but requires iteration @Bond approach is more efficient if you just want to workout the working days by subtracting the number of Sundays in a month.

Comment: Scrap that its just more efficient. :)

Answer (score -1):

How about using "The Weekday function returns a number between 1 and 7, that represents the day of the week." ?